# Call cy.log in a chain of calls

Tags: cypress, cypress-log

I am trying to log something in the middle of a Cypress chain of calls:

```js
function geAccountElement() {
    return cy.get('div[ui-id=account]')
        .then(thing => {
            cy.log('Peek at thing: ' + thing);
            return thing;
        })
        .contains(testAccountName)
        .parents('div[ui-id=account-card]')
}
```

But I am getting this warning:

```
Command `contains` expects ["element", "cy"] as a previous subject, but "any" is passed from `then` command
```

How can I make this sort of chainable logging function work?

---

Update Saturday 23 March 2024, 06:20:04 PM

Turns out I was even more confused. I saw that warning in an IntelliJ tool tip but did not run the test. If I did, I would have seen:

```
cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.

In your callback function you invoked 1 or more cy commands but then returned a synchronous value.
```

What I am trying to do is log the thing in between chained calls. I see I can do this:

```js
cy.get('div[ui-id=account]')
.invoke('val')
.then(thing => {
    cy.log('Peek at thing: ' + thing);
})
```

But that's a terminal operation.. meaning the rest of the test stops there. I wanted to try and get some logging happening between `get` and the `contains`.

Comment: I can't reproduce it- looks like it's a type error, can you show the tsconfig?

Comment: Also title says `cy.log()` but that produces an error of a different kind. I assume that's why your code now has `console.log()`?

Comment: Sorry, should be `cy.log()`. Updated the question.

Comment: Can you confirm the exact error message, because the one you post is different to the one I get.

Comment: Also, where do you see the error? Is it in the Cypress runner log pane?

Comment: Updated the question. You are right - there was a different error. Trying to explain more clearly what I want to do: add logging in the middle of a chain of calls. I suspect I am getting confused with sync vs async calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my test, the error about mixed async and sync code was fixed by wrapping the return value like this:

```js
cy.visit('https://example.com');

cy.get('h1')
  .then(thing => {
      cy.log('Peek at thing: ' + thing)   // this is an async command
      // return thing                     // this line is the "sync" value complained about
      return cy.wrap(thing)               // wrapping makes it async
  })
  .contains('Example Domain')
```

[image]

Cypress is not overly smart about this error message, since the `cy.log()` is just a side effect and has no bearing on the chain subject (i.e `return thing` is acceptable without the cy.log).

You can instead swap in the synchronous `Cypress.log()` call

```js
cy.get('h1')
  .then(thing => {
      Cypress.log({
        message: 'Peek at thing: ' + thing
      })
      return thing
  })
  .contains('Example Domain')
```

and make use of other properties for more informative log

```js
cy.get('h1')
  .then(thing => {
      Cypress.log({
        displayName: 'Peek at thing:',
        message: thing
      })
      return thing
  })
  .contains('Example Domain')
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you @K.Kassianides. You have made a frustrating day considerably more bearable, and taught me how I can get some useful logging out!